# How to test if directories starting with "xx" exist?

Tags: bash

How to test directories starting with "xx" exist. such as `xx-a/ xx-b/ xx-c/`. How to test them exist.

```
packagePath="xx*"

if [[ -d $packagePath ]]; then
    rm -rf $packagePath
fi
```

I try this but not work.

Comment: Use `[..]` instead of `[[..]]`.

Comment: It works :) Can you tell me why?

Comment: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: It only works when only one directory matches the pattern.

Comment: @user3130007: `man bash`: _Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed  on  the words  between  the  [[  and  ]];_

Comment: @choroba: You're right. I assumed there was only one `xx*` directory but user3130007 did not state this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there can be more than one such a directory,j but `-d` only wants one. Also, order of expansions is important.

```
dirs=( $packagePath )
if [[ -d ${packagePath[0]} ]] ; then
    rm -rf "${packagePath[@]}"
fi
```

Also, once the wildcards expanded, you know the directories were there, so there's no need to test their existence again:

```
dirs=( $packagePath/ )
if [[ ${packagePath[0]} != *\*/ ]] ; then
    rm -rf "${packagePath[@]}"
fi
```

But if you only want to remove them, you don't have to test for existence. Simply

```
rm -rf $packagePath
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real need for an explicit test. Adding a `/` to the end of the pattern will *only* match directories.

```
rm -rf xx*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
#To check at least one directory starting with xx exist
var=( xx* ) # * will glob for everything that start with xx
for i in "${var[@]}"
do 
  [ -d "$i" ] && echo "exists" && break
done
```